# Using Twitter OpenAuth

Tags: oauth, twitter

I am currently starting a project that will interact with Twitter via it's OpenAuth system and I was wondering about a few of the details.  If a user agrees to give my site access to their Twitter account, can I access their account even if they aren't on my site?  For example, could I have a nightly job run that would pull in all of the user's tweets and information without the user actually having to access my site?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You wouldn't be able to do this if Twitter's access tokens expired, but they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, a few sites I have allowed access to my own twitter account have had there script run nightly to post there spam tweets on everyones account that they had access to.

Comment: At least it has to be ran from your server... Its not like someone can steal all the credentials go to town on their own server.